# Label in BarChart?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

Is it anyhow possible to set the label into the bar chart?

Like this example:
I couldnt find an example on the official page: [Official example page](https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/TinyBarChart)
[image]

//EDIT

Later I had other problems, but I was able to solve them by switching to Nivo Charts.  [Nivo Charts](https://nivo.rocks/bar/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using label `options` in this way:

```
options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            autoSkip: false,
            maxRotation: 90,
            minRotation: 90,
            padding: -110
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

The result is:

[image]

[This](https://codesandbox.io/s/chart-js-forked-j4mxs?file=/src/index.js) is a codesandbox example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LabelList component with a custom render, here is the link of the documentation:

https://recharts.org/en-US/api/LabelList

also you can use the position property to center it inside the bar , here is an example of a customized LabelList :
https://recharts.org/en-US/examples/BarChartWithMinHeight